# Get values of key in object dynamicaly

Tags: javascript

I get the values of the first or `NAMED` key in the object. This one is called `Efficacy`.

```
var PSEQ_Obj = $.parseJSON( PSEQ );
var PSEQ_dps1 = PSEQ_Obj.Efficacy;
```

But I want to know if there is a dynamic way to do this.
For instance. Bellow will return `Efficacy`.

```
for (label in PSEQ_Obj) break;
```

But I cant use it lik follows

```
var PSEQ_dps1 = PSEQ_Obj.label;
```

So this `label` is a dynamic, but you cant call it exactly like above.
Is there a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `bracket notation` instead of `dot notation` when accessing properties that are stored in variables as follows :

```
var PSEQ_dps1 = PSEQ_Obj[label];
```

you can read more about [this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) on MDN.

Comment: which ones. `{}` , `[]` , `()`